# jQuery: How to check if after input there is a label

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How do I check if label tag exist after input tag?

I have this code

```
$j(document).ready(function () {
    $j('input[type="checkbox"],input[type="radio"]').each(function () {


    });
});
```

I want to check immediately after `input[type:checkbox]` and `input[tyoe:radio]` if there is label tag.

If yes then do nothing, if no then add an empty label tag `<label></label>`

Anyone know how?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use jQuery [next()](https://api.jquery.com/next/) to see if next element is label. You will get length = 0 if there is not label. Once you know if you have label next to input element you can use [after()](http://api.jquery.com/after/) to insert element after the current element.

```
if(!$j(this).next('label').length)
   $j(this).after('<label></label>');
```